# Getting Error: I want to connect pyAdmin (Installed on Windows) with postgreSQL on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I want to connect pgadmin (Windows) with postgreSQL-11.18 (Ubuntu 22.04) and getting error: **connection timeout error**

I am following steps from: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFFXr.png)

I have started postgres as mentioned in steps:
[Started postgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgRIJ.png)

While Connecting with pgAdmin I am getting this error: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lunJ8.png)

I have followed the same steps as mentioned.

If anyone had encountered already, need help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install pgadmin on windows native, with postgres server on WSL Arch linux following the tutorial you mentioned but with a few changes:

1. Run postgres server on WSL: `pg_ctl -D <your database directory> start`, the output was this:

```
╰─❯ pg_ctl -D $PGDATA16 start
waiting for server to start....2023-07-13 12:08:01.660 -03 [4659] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16beta1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 13.1.1 20230429, 64-bit
2023-07-13 12:08:01.662 -03 [4659] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-07-13 12:08:01.676 -03 [4659] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-07-13 12:08:01.707 -03 [4662] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-30 17:18:29 -03
2023-07-13 12:08:01.738 -03 [4659] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

2. Get the second line of the output `listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432`
3. While adding a new server on pgadmin, in the "connection" tab, you need to put Host name/address the IPv4 address you saw in the output: 127.0.0.1.
4. Maintenance databse needs to be the **name** of the database of your postgres installation. You can see the available databases with the command `psql --list` on WSL.
5. Username needs to be the username you connect to postgres on WSL, and the password needs to be the one you login to your username. You can save it.
6. Give a good name to your connection on the general tab and save it.